# How to sort on columns generated by an angular expression in primeng table?

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable

Trying to sort a table in PrimeNG table which has a field which is generated as a multiplication of values of two other fields. My problem here is that I can't modify the object array which the table is based on but so i need to multiply them as an angular expression and add it to the table. But I also need to sort the table with this field, which does not have a field name, since it is calculated through expression. How do I specify this field in pSortableColumn or field name? Now I am able to sort with all fields except the one being calculated.

```
<tr>
    <th [pSortableColumn]="prop.field" *ngFor="let prop of fieldList">{{prop.header}} <p-sortIcon [field]="prop.field"></p-sortIcon></th>                        
    <th [pSortableColumn]="">Product<p-sortIcon [field]=""></p-sortIcon></th>
</tr>
```

```
<tr>              
              <td *ngFor="let prop of fieldList">                                    
                      {{ rowData[prop.field] }}      
              </td>
              <td>
                {{+rowData['Qty'] * +rowData['Cost']}}
              </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `customSort` ?